# Read directory from InteliJ gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am in the development of creating a plugin using Java 17.

Went to page 5 on google results trying to find an answer but couldn't get to one, possibly because I'm googling the wrong thing?

My plugin is currently being tested using `runIDE` through Gradle. However, when deploying using `buildPlugin` it yields the same result.

Upon a tonne of similar answers none of them work as it returns:

```
/Users/USERNAME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/2021.2.2/aa03fa700ac9c82d03acad5eadd5e547b5ccc008/ideaIC-2021.2.2/bin
```

This is the path to towards the gradle plugin and not the directory I am working with:

Expecting: `/Users/USERNAME/Documents/PROJECT`

Tried:

```
File directory = new File("./");
System.out.print(directory.getCanonicalPath());
```

```
Path root = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("").toAbsolutePath();
Path filePath = Paths.get(root.toString());
```

Comment: IDEA can have many projects open at once, so there's no reason to expect the working directory to be a particular project. Have a look at https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/project-structure.html

Comment: Yeah I saw this and thought it is overkill just for the general-purpose I need to do. If this is the only way then I'll take a further look into it, thanks